# Restore Shift+Deleted builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, restore

Is there a way to recover builds that were shift+deleted in Jenkins? 
I saw the other thread but I think it was only for delete and not for shift+delete
Please help. I lost a few builds from my production job

Answer (score 1):

Even if the build was deleted from disk, you should have the build log and you can get the Changelist at which the build was made and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Jenkins on Windows and you performed the Shift+Delete on the job folder itself in Windows Explorer:

No.<sup>*</sup>  Jenkins stores all job data in that directory and Windows deletes the files immediately using that method.  You will need to restore the jobs from backup if you have them.

<sup>*Note: Unless you use a file system level recovery tool, which is out of scope for this exchange. You could ask over on [Superuser](http://superuser.com).</sup>